# Firestore database duplicates entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Unsure why, but my "live chat" website duplicates an entry to firestore. I've been stuck on this for a bit and hoping someone could give me a hand.

Please give me a hand if you see any issues as to why this would happen; once you enter a message and click submit, it adds it to the database twice.

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
    messageInput();
})


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    if (user) {
        console.log("Signed in")
        displayName = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;  
        el.innerHTML = "<b>Username:</b> " + displayName;
        // document.getElementById("chat-response").style.visibility = "visible;"
        } else {
        // document.getElementById("chat-response").style.visibility = "hidden;"
        el.innerHTML = "You are not currently signed in";
        console.log("Not signed in")
    }
});

// get live data
db.collection("messages").orderBy("timestamp")
.onSnapshot(function(m){
    let list = [];
    document.querySelector(".chat-area").innerHTML = "";
        m.forEach(m => {
            list.push(m.data());
        });

        document.querySelector(".chat-area").innerHTML = render(list)
});

function render(list) {
output = list.map(m => `<p><strong> ${m.username}: </strong> ${m.message}</p>`).join("");
    return output;
}

function messageInput(){
    let messageValue;
    messageValue = document.querySelector("#message").value;

    if(!messageValue){
        return;
    }
    else {
        db.collection("messages").add({
            // username: displayName,
            // emailAddress: email,
            message: messageValue,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the function messageInput() is the only place that calls add(), place a console.log in the function and click submit.  How many times is the messageInput() function called for one submit click?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I'd like to suggest that you also read this ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Stackoverflow is a great place to ask questions but the community asks that you take time in posting questions and try and make them as clear as possible.

Comment: That’s what I first tried, it only calls it once. I am also using a browser-sync node module. Unsure if that could cause that, doubt it though

Comment: Do you have some triggers in your firebase database? Maybe after you insert you insert again :) Some leftovers from playing around?